# Searching Pandas Column for string where each row value contains list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that each values is a list

| Component |
| --- |
| [R797,R398] |
| [R803,R93] |

I am trying to search within the columns to find a specific component like R797

What I have tried is `df[df['component'].str.contains('R797')]` but it returns an empty table even though the value is clearly is within the list.

I been trying to iterate through the list but each time it say the list isn't hashable any suggestions would be great

Comment: Are all the list of the same size?

Comment: No they are all different sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create series:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([['R797','R398'],['R803','R93']])
```

result:

```
0    [R797, R398]
1     [R803, R93]
```

Now `apply` lambda function to each element (list):

```
s.apply(lambda s: 'R797' in s)
```

output:

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

To find an element:

```
s[s.apply(lambda s: 'R797' in s)]
```

result:

```
0    [R797, R398]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This worked for me! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) + [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to find the corresponding indices:

```
import pandas as pd

# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[["R797","R398"]], [["R803","R93"]]], columns=["Component"])

# explode (un-nest) list, then find, and group by index
mask = df.explode("Component").eq("R797").groupby(level=0).any().values

res = df[mask]
print(res)

      Component
0  [R797, R398]
```